# Least Squares Solution and Singular Vector

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there a simple way to show that the least square solution of an overdetermined linear system is equal to the right singular vector of the coefficient matrix corresponding to the smallest singular value?

Comment: It seems to me that there is information missing about the nature of the right hand side.

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you mean by simple, but here's how I like to think of it:

Let $A$ be our coefficient matrix, with SVD $A = U\Sigma V^T$.  Our system of equations is
$$
Ax = b \implies\\
U \Sigma V^T x = b
$$
if we make the substitution $y = V^T x$ (that is, $x = Vy$), then this equation can be rewritten in the form
$$
\Sigma y = (U^Tb)
$$
because $\Sigma$ is the diagonal matrix with singular values, we can find the least squares solution to this problem "by looking at it".  In other words, once you write things out, you should be able to solve *this* problem directly.  It's enough then to note that once you have *this* solution, you can work back towards the *general* solution by undoing our substitution.